# How it's possible a binary is not changed when increasing optimization flag?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, icc

I've compiled the same program for different optimization flags: `-O0`, `-O1`, `-O2`, and `-O3`. I've used both gcc and icc. Below you can see a fragment of the make file:

```
build-gcc-O3: CXX = g++
build-gcc-O3: BIN_POST_NAME = -gcc-O3
build-gcc-O3: OPT_FLAGS = -O3
build-gcc-O3: fluidsGL

build-icc-O0: CXX = $(INTEL_ICPC)
build-icc-O0: BIN_POST_NAME = -icc-O0
build-icc-O0: OPT_FLAGS = -O0
build-icc-O0: fluidsGL

fluidsGL: fluidsGL.o fluidsGL_cpu.o bilinear_interpolation.o defines.o
   $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(BINARY_DIR)/defines.o $(BINARY_DIR)/bilinear_interpolation.o $(BINARY_DIR)/fluidsGL_cpu.o $(BINARY_DIR)/fluidsGL.o -o $(BINARY_DIR)/$@$(BIN_POST_NAME)$(DBG_NAME_APPEND) $(OPT_FLAGS) -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglut -lfftw3f
```

After running make, the output looks fine. For example, this is the make resultant command for icc with `-O3`:

```
"/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/bin/intel64/icpc" -Wall bin/defines.o bin/bilinear_interpolation.o bin/fluidsGL_cpu.o bin/fluidsGL.o -o bin/fluidsGL-icc-O3 -O3 -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW -lglut -lfftw3f
```

After compiling, fluidsGL-gcc-O0 and fluidsGL-gcc-O3 (and fluidsGL-icc-O0 vs fluidsGL-icc-O3) binaries need the same disk space, this already seems strange for me:

```
$ ls -la bin/ 
total 728
drwxrwxr-x 3 jesus jesus  4096 ene 18 09:56 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 jesus jesus  4096 ene 18 09:31 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jesus jesus  4200 ene 18 09:56 bilinear_interpolation.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jesus jesus  5608 ene 18 09:56 defines.o
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jesus jesus 14952 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL_cpu.o
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jesus jesus 30780 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL-gcc-O0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jesus jesus 43940 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL-gcc-O0-dbg
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jesus jesus 44272 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL-gcc-O0-dbg-gprof
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jesus jesus 30780 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL-gcc-O1
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jesus jesus 30780 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL-gcc-O2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jesus jesus 30780 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL-gcc-O3
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jesus jesus 71151 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL-icc-O0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jesus jesus 71151 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL-icc-O1
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jesus jesus 71151 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL-icc-O2
-rwxrwxr-x 1 jesus jesus 71151 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL-icc-O3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jesus jesus 34664 ene 18 09:56 fluidsGL.o
```

But even after using diff to compare the files no output is displayed, meaning the binaries are the same exact binaries:

```
$ diff bin/fluidsGL-gcc-O0 bin/fluidsGL-gcc-O3
$ diff bin/fluidsGL-icc-O0 bin/fluidsGL-icc-O3
$
```

Is this a normal behaviour of the compiler or am I making a building mistake?

Comment: What's the code? Maybe it's too simple?

Comment: Did you try a recompile? I know the problem when changing from debug to profile compilation that make does only takes edits of source code not changes of makefile / compilerflags to determine if a source file needs to be recompiled.

Comment: @KirilKirov The code is fairly complex, it's a CPU port of the CUDA stable fluids simulation where I perform fluid advection, diffusion, projection. I use OpenGL to display how particles are moving in the canvas. The mathematical background can be read  here: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch38.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-Ox` flags (where `x` is the optimization level) are for compiler optimizations, but you're not actually re-compiling. You're just re-linking the already compiled object (`.o`) files.

Make sure to add the `-Ox` flag to the compilation commands for the object files, and do a full clean rebuild.

Answer (score 3):

It is most likely a build mistake .... or you expecting the makefile to produce a rebuild, despite not having set it up to do so.

Object files can typically be linked together, even if built using different optimisation settings.   So `make` will not typically delete object files or rebuild them simply because you have specified a change of optimisation setting.

If you watch the progress of the build, you will probably see the second build not doing any recompile or relinking.

Set up something akin to a `clean` target in the makefile, which removes the compiled objects (*.o) and the executables.   And do a `make clean` between the two builds you want to compare (after ensuring you keep the executable, of course, otherwise you can't compare them).

It is possible that your code is so simple it doesn't benefit from a change of optimisation settings.   But I doubt it.